# How to upload files on changing the select menu options using multer in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, ajax, mongoose, file-upload, handlebars.js

I want to upload the files on changing the select menu option bar. First I upload the files by choosing files from "Choose Files" option. Then on clicking select menu I choose "Done" option from Status column.

On choosing this option I want this action means I want all the files get uploaded to the database with POST AJAX or with any other means if possible. How can I achieve that?
Below is the UI code for select menu option and Upload option:

[image]

HANDELBAR SIDE CODE:
I am trying this code:

```
 <td>
      <div class="center">
    <select name="sources" id="{{this.commonID}}" class="custom-select sources" placeholder="{{this.status}}">
      <option value="0" selected="selected">In Progress</option>
      <option value="1" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">Done</option>
      <option value="2">Rejected</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  </td>
    <td><span id="deadline"> {{this.deadline}}</span></td>
    <td>
      <input type="file" id="{{this.commonID}}" class="btn btn-outline-warning" name="FileUploadForClient" multiple />
    </td>
```

And in index.js this  is my multer code:

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, './public/files')
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    x = file.originalname; //+path.extname(file.originalname);
  cb(null,x);
  }
});

var upload = multer({storage: storage});
```

Answer (score 0):

you should define a post request almost like this;

```
app.post('/uploadImages', upload.array('imageArray', 5), (req, res, next) => {
    const files = req.files;
    if (!files) {
        throw err;
        }

        res.send(files);
    }
```

Comment: i know this but that is not what i asked. I want that AJAX code for calling the POST route.